# Отображение frame по ходу выполнения

Tags: objective-c

Дело такое: надо отобразить изменение свойства frame у объекта до того когда выполнится метод. Например:

```
- (void)run{
    [self turnRight];
    [self move];
    [self move];
    [self move];
}
- (IBAction)move {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:self.delayTimeInterval];
        if ([self frontIsClear]) {
            CGRect newFrame = self.person.frame;
            CGPoint newPoint = newFrame.origin;
            if ([person.dirrection isEqualToString:@"Up"]) newPoint.y-=HERO_SIZE;
            else if ([person.dirrection isEqualToString:@"Right"]) newPoint.x+=HERO_SIZE;
            else if ([person.dirrection isEqualToString:@"Down"]) newPoint.y+=HERO_SIZE;
            else if ([person.dirrection isEqualToString:@"Left"]) newPoint.x-=HERO_SIZE;
            newFrame.origin = newPoint;
            [self.person setFrame:newFrame];
            [self updateUserInfo];
        }
    }
```

Пока получается только сразу так: на 3 клетки прыгает и ждет `3*self.delayTimeInterval`

Comment: @ua24, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Вы изменяете фрейм три раза в течении одного прохода run loop. А перерисовка всего, что было изменено, как мы знаем, производится в следующем цикле отрисовки. Когда же начнется этот новый цикл отрисовки? Очевидно, что в новом проходе run loop. А новый проход run loop не начнется, пока не закончится текущий. А в текущем стоят подряд все три вызова по изменению фрейма. То есть именно поэтому все три изменения подряд (как одно) Вы и видите.

Советы для наиболее простого решения проблемы:

- в методе move уберите sleep (который Вы, кстати, вызываете для main thread, повергая приложение в глобальную "спячку")
- там же используйте анимацию [UIView animateWithDuration...], все-таки выглядеть все станет значительно приятнее
- в методе run напишите комплексную анимацию на все три сдвига вместо трех вызовов move

Можно так же попробовать поработать с CAKeyframeAnimation, но это более сложно и может занять больше времени.

Comment: все так но проблема в том что набор команд в методе run будут писать люди и их там может быть до ста скажем с учетом циклов и проверкой разных условий уже как только не пробывал делал single queue dispatch_queue_t otherQ = dispatch_queue_create("otherQ", NULL); через нее запускал run а в методе move присваивал фрейм переходя в main_queue так вроди и работало но когда через цикл начинаеш вызывать move из run - поведение программы мягко говоря НЕПРЕДВИДЕННОЕ (какието команды выполняются, остальные игнорятся просто) HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: Прийдите к концепции "Последовательность анимаций". Для примера можно посмотреть как это реализовано в том же Cocos2d. Самый простой вариант выхода из ситуации который я вижу:
1. Создать как мембер класса NSMutableArray *animations; куда Вы будете складывать все анимации, что приходят подряд.
2. В методе move добавлять тип анимации в animations и если она первая, то запускать эту анимацию.
3. В completionHandler анимации удалять выполнившуюся анимацию из animations проверять, если есть еще анимации в animations, то запускать следующую

Comment: Что-то типа

    - (IBAction) move {
        NSString *animationType = ...;
        [self.animations addObject:animationType];
        if ([self.animations count] == 1) {
            [self performAnimation];
        }
    }

Comment: И:

    - (void) performAnimation {
        NSString *animationType = [self.animations firstObject];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                         animations:^{
                             // Ваша анимация
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [self.animations removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                             if ([self.animations count]) {
                                 [self performAnimation];
                             }
                         }];
    }